# record not saving when before_save action is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Can't figure this out.. Not sure why the record isn't being saved.. the method is being called properly, and all the fields are present, and the logic is correct.. Here is my model code:

```
class Mine < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :shop
validates :merchant_id, presence: true
validates :auth_token, presence: true
before_save :assign_three_speed


private

  def assign_three_speed
    if CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?
    (self.marketplace)
      self.three_speed = false
    else
      self.three_speed = true     
    end
  end
end
```

Well this is super crazy.. I put in some loggers and now it DOES save?? This is my code now:

```
  def assign_three_speed
    Rails.logger.info "What is self?? #{self.inspect}"
    if CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?
     (self.marketplace)
      self.three_speed = false
    else
      self.three_speed = true     
    end
    Rails.logger.info "Now what is self?? #{self.inspect}"
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions of Rails prior to 5.0.0, returning false from a callback method will cancel the save. From the Rails 4.2.7 documentation:

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the
>   order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.

When setting `self.three_speed = false`, it is the last statement that is run in the method, so that false is the return value of the assign_three_speed method. That's why adding the logger to the last line fixed it. Have the method return some other value instead.

Return true as the last line if you never want to cancel the callback:

```
def assign_three_speed
  if CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include(self.marketplace)
    self.three_speed = false
  else
    self.three_speed = true     
  end

  true
end
```